# PHP highlight selected item

Tags: php, html, css

[image]

Just like the image above, when the user clicks one of the list on the right side, it highlights the selected one.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM contacts") or die(mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $company = $row['eyo_company_name'];
    $id = $row['con_id'];
    $editLinks .= "\n\t<a href=\"edit.php?id=$id\">$company</a><br>";
}
```

this is how I brought the list out from the database. Would there be any way I could add a class or add b tag on selected one only ?

Comment: You should use javascript for that

Comment: CSS pseudo class :active

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to highlight one of the links output by PHP. To do so you will need to know which one to highlight.

If you have a GET variable set to the current contact ID, you could do something like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $company = $row['eyo_company_name'];
    $id = $row['con_id'];

    //let's check if we've pre-selected a company
    //  and if so, is this the company we selected?
    if (true === array_key_exists('CURRENT_COMPANY_ID', $_GET) && $id === $_GET['CURRENT_COMPANY_ID']) {

        //we did select this company for this PHP request
        //  let's make the HTML output custom to highlight the selected company
        $editLinks .= "\n\t<a href=\"edit.php?id=$id\"><strong>$company</strong></a><br>";
    } else {
        $editLinks .= "\n\t<a href=\"edit.php?id=$id\">$company</a><br>";
    }
}
```

This example expects that your request to the PHP script generating your list of links will include `CURRENT_COMPANY_ID=<ID HERE>` in the URL.

For example, if the URL for the request that generates your list of links looks like this:

```
/getMySuperAwesomeList.php
```

It would need to look like this:

```
/getMySuperAwesomeList.php?CURRENT_COMPANY_ID=123
```

Where `123` matches the `con_id` of the record you want to highlight.

I chose to use `array_key_exists()` to make sure that the request actually included the `CURRENT_COMPANY_ID` data in the URL. Here is documentation for that function: https://www.php.net/array_key_exists

Comment: Thanks ! Now I get the concept. I just used $id == $_GET['id'] instead, and it works perfectly.